# SolrCloud: How can I search all collections available without knowing the individual names?

Tags: collections, solr, solrcloud

Using solrcloud 4.6, let's say I have a 8 node cluster with a shard running on each node and many different collections. Basically a collections is made each day (to partition the data). Now the question is how to search all of the collection without knowing their names?

The wiki says I can do this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?collection=collection1_NY,collection1_NJ,collection1_CT
```

which is basically searching multiple collections at the same time. But in my case collections are dynamically created and I don't know the current names.

Is there a way to send a generic search query that hits all the collections?

Or a way to specify a *range* of collections like `collection1-10` or `collection*2013`?

I also know I can hook into the ZK and get the info but that would be too advanced for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be done with [SOLR-5466](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5466) (EDIT this is done as of 4.8), but has no patch ready yet...

In [this question on the mailing list](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Listing-Collections-in-Solr-Cloud-td4101752.html) two workarounds are given, both retrieving the info from zookeeper, via api call or parsing html response to a get.

Here are the two workarounds:

1. ZK client API
   you could just do a get_children on the zk node
   /collections/ to get all collections.
2. without ZK client API point this url at your solrCloud install

   href="http://host:port/solr/zookeeper?detail=true&path=%2Fcollections

you should be looking for children under the collections node.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although this is not my desired answer but at least confirms that there are no "list" functionality built in yet. Tnx.

Comment: How was this not part of the original SOLR application? This seems like such a huge oversight :/

Answer (score 1):

I found the list of collections by requesting:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=LIST
```

My Solr version is: 8.7.0

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you need to know something about the collections and you create alias for a group of collections. 
You can do something like this:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=AliasName&collection=ListOfCollections
```

More on this topic:`http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/10/collection-aliasing-near-real-time-search-for-really-big-data/`